# When to use gerunds

Tags: gerunds

Originating 200 years ago, modern fencing is a close-quarter combat sport where two opponents face off each other in a contest of skill, speed and agility.

Is the word 'originating' used as a gerund? i understand that gerunds can be used as the subject or the object of a sentence but it doesn't seem to be the case here. Can the word be 'originated'?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a present participle.

Comment: In modern grammar, we don't distinguish between gerunds and participles. We just call them both 'gerund-participles'.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as StoneyB mentions, it's what some linguists call the "present participle" since "originating 200 years ago" is an *adjective phrase* that modifies "modern fencing".

[Don't mistake a gerund for a participle](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm)

However, user178049 counters that modern grammar doesn't distinguish between these, and groups them together as "gerund-participles".  I suggest they fence to determine who is correct.

Comment: I'm with StoneyB on this one!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to understand whether there's a gerund phrase or a participle phrase is to know that "**gerund phrases**" are always either the object or the subject in a sentence (or even both). "**Participle phrases**" always act like *adjectives* that modify the object or the subject in a sentence.

1. Running with scissors, Michael accidentally stabbed a passerby. *(Participle phrase "Running with scissors" modifies the subject "Michael" in the sentence)*
2. Running with scissors is dangerous. *(Gerund phrase "Running with scissors" is the subject in the sentence)*